# Parsing specific data from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, parsing

I have a json file which is the result of an API call:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "barometer": {
        "hg": 29.26,
        "hpa": 991,
        "kpa": 99.09,
        "mb": 990.92
      },
      "ceiling": {
        "base_feet_agl": 3800,
        "base_meters_agl": 1158,
        "code": "BKN",
        "feet": 3800,
        "meters": 1158,
        "text": "Broken"
      },
      "clouds": [
        {
          "base_feet_agl": 3300,
          "base_meters_agl": 1006,
          "code": "SCT",
          "feet": 3300,
          "meters": 1006,
          "text": "Scattered"
        },
        {
          "base_feet_agl": 3800,
          "base_meters_agl": 1158,
          "code": "BKN",
          "feet": 3800,
          "meters": 1158,
          "text": "Broken"
        }
      ],
      "conditions": [
        {
          "code": "RA",
          "text": "Rain"
        }
      ],
      "dewpoint": {
        "celsius": 8,
        "fahrenheit": 46
      },
      "elevation": {
        "feet": 75,
        "meters": 23
      },
      "flight_category": "VFR",
      "humidity": {
        "percent": 72
      },
      "icao": "EGGP",
      "observed": "2021-05-03T18:20Z",
      "raw_text": "EGGP 031820Z AUTO 23013KT 9999 RA SCT033/// BKN038/// 13/08 Q0991",
      "station": {
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
            -2.84972,
            53.333599
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        "location": "Liverpool, GB",
        "name": "Liverpool John Lennon Airport",
        "type": "Airport"
      },
      "temperature": {
        "celsius": 13,
        "fahrenheit": 55
      },
      "visibility": {
        "meters": "10,000+",
        "meters_float": 9999,
        "miles": "Greater than 6",
        "miles_float": 6.21
      },
      "wind": {
        "degrees": 230,
        "speed_kph": 24,
        "speed_kts": 13,
        "speed_mph": 15,
        "speed_mps": 7
      }
    }
  ],
  "results": 1
}
```

I need to parse specific parts of the file, but no matter what I try there always seems to be an error. Here is one of the scripts I've tried: **please excuse any messy coding, I am a beginner who is learning!:

```
import requests
import json

def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print (text)


icao = string = input("enter airport name")  # establishing preferred location
hdr = {"X-API-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
url = requests.get(f'https://api.checkwx.com/metar/{icao}/decoded', headers=hdr)
# above is the API call, I have inserted the variable 'icao' into the location field.
data = url.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
data1 = parsed["data"]["wind"]
print(data1)
```

So if I wanted to extract the wind part from the file as above, it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I have tried near enough everything along with my computing teacher but we get a variety of errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: `parsed['data']` is a list which contains a dict. `parsed['data'][0]['wind']` should give you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
print(x["data"][0]["wind"])
```

This is because x["data"] returns you something like `[{}]`.